# Access name of image in django models

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I want to add a watermark to an image in django from database, for this I have to access Image name in String format 
Currently I am Using this Technique

`original_pic = Photo.objects.values('original_pic')
image = Image.open(original_pic.values()).convert('RGBA')`

but my 'original_pic' is of dictionary type, It returns data in QuerySet

`<QuerySet [{'original_pic': 'temp4.jpg'}, {'original_pic': 'facebook.jfif'}, {'original_pic': 'html.png'}, {'original_pic': '1001.jpg'}, {'original_pic': '1002.jpg'}, {'original_pic': '1003.jpg'}, {'original_pic': '1005.jpg'}, {'original_pic': '1007.jpg'}, {'original_pic': '1018.jpg'}, {'original_pic': '1009.jpg'}, {'original_pic': '1010.jpg'}, {'original_pic': '1011.jpg'}, {'original_pic': '1012.jpg'}, {'original_pic': '1016.jpg'}, {'original_pic': 'unity.png'}, {'original_pic': 'linkedin1.jpg'}, {'original_pic': 'android.png'}, {'original_pic': '1027.PNG'}, {'original_pic': 'github.jpg'}]>`

I want to retrieve data in Plain String Format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
original_pic = Photo.objects.values_list('original_pic', flat=True)
```

Note `flat=True` argument. From docs:

> If you only pass in a single field, you can also pass in the flat parameter. If True, this will mean the returned results are single values, rather than one-tuples

Answer (score 0):

It's not a 100% clear for me what you mean by plain string format. But if you want to have a list of strings of your photo model with the file path for a `FileField/ImageField` you can do:

```
[photo.original_pic.path for photo in Photo.objects.all()]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you are trying to open a **single image**. For that, you have to filter the `Photo` queryset with [**`filter()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#filter) method and fetch the result using [**`values_list()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

```
original_pic = Photo.objects.filter(id=photo_id).values_list('original_pic', flat=True)[0]
image = Image.open(original_pic).convert('RGBA')
```

Comment: This only retrieves data of particular id. What if I want to get data for complete Column. i.e **original_pic**.

Comment: If so, use  @neverwalkaloner's answer